# Why is only first value of select tag selected after click submit button?

Tags: php, html

I just want to know why is only first value of select tag selected when I click submit button, though I select 2nd or more option?

```
<div class="form-group my-3">
   <select class="form-control" name="role">
      <option value="">Select your role</option>
      <option value="1"  <?=(isset($_SESSION['role'])==1) ? 'selected': ''; unset($_SESSION['role']) ?> >Admin</option>
      <option value="2" <?=(isset($_SESSION['role'])==2) ? 'selected': ''; unset($_SESSION['role']) ?>>Modarator</option>
      <option value="3" <?=(isset($_SESSION['role'])==3) ? 'selected': ''; unset($_SESSION['role']) ?>>Editor</option>
   </select
<!-- error msg if role is not selected -->
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['role_empty'])){ ?>
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
           <?php echo $_SESSION['role_empty']; ?>
         </div>                    
    <?php } unset($_SESSION['role_empty']); ?>
</div>
```

I expect Editor or Modarator, but only I got Admin why?

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['role'])` (see [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)) will always return `true` or `false`.  Doing lose comparison, that equates to either 1 or 0.

Comment: Why should submitting the form submit multiple values? That is a single-select field through which only one single value can be selected and submitted

Answer (score 1):

By default, `<select>` appears as a dropdown box, and only allows you to select one `<option>` element at a time. This can be overridden by using the `multiple` attribute, which tells the browser to render the element as a list box and allow for multiple items to be selected. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left-click to select multiple elements manually.

```html
<select class="form-control" name="role" placeholder="Select your role" multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>Admin</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Moderator</option>
  <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>
```